# Logout user on tab closed

Tags: forms-authentication, login

We have site with forms based authentication. When user logs in and closes browser (whole browser) he is logged out. But when he closes tab in which he opened site, he is still logged in when he reopens tab and opens site again.

How we can logout user/kill session when tab in browser is closed?

Answer (score 1):

That's a browser issue. The whole browser is required to be closed because the session information is still in the browser. The answer here is that it is a training issue to make sure users log out properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build in some mechanism where it will check if user is still active or not, if for some periode of time the users wasn't active on the website he could be automatically logged out. If this approach is possible you could try it.